# Removing http:// prefix from ASP loaded URL

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

[My page here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/nightlife/pubs/horse-and-groom-593.html#.Ul6QxFCc_eK) has advertisers' URLs listed in full, but I'm not sure how to remove the http:// prefix.

Here's the Code:

```
 <% if instr("abc"&rsAdvert("WebAddress"),"http:")>0 then
     shttp=""
 else
     shttp="http://" 
 %>
 <li class="weblink"> 
   | <a onclick="pageTracker._trackPageview('/TOP_FULL_ADVERT_WEBSITE/<%=shttp%><%=rsAdvert("WebAddress")%>');"
        href='<%=shttp%><%=rsAdvert("WebAddress")%>'
        target='_blank' rel='nofollow'>
    <%=rsAdvert("WebAddress")%></a></li>
<% end if %>
```

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
var url = "your url";
url = url.replace("http://", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this bit of your code:

```
<a href="url">text</a>
              ^^^^
```

You link looks like this:

```
<a 
    onclick="pageTracker._trackPageview('/TOP_FULL_ADVERT_WEBSITE/<%=shttp%><%=rsAdvert("WebAddress")%>');" 
    href='<%=shttp%><%=rsAdvert("WebAddress")%>' 
    target='_blank' 
    rel='nofollow'>
    <%=rsAdvert("WebAddress")%>
</a>
```

so you need to chnage the bit just before the `</a>`, specifically this bit at the end

```
><%=rsAdvert("WebAddress")%></a>
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

to some variable which does not include the http://

this might work, not sure of classic asp syntax

```
 ><%=rsAdvert("WebAddress").replace("http://", "")%></a>
```

Comment: try lower case .replace....