# Remove the http://localhost prefix from the url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

In my angular code

```
app.directive("myDom", function ($compile) {
var url = "\'https://examples.form.io/simple\'";
return {
    link: function (scope, element) {           
        var template = '<formio src="' +url+ '"></formio><button>ClickMe</button>';
        var linkFn = $compile(template);
        var content = linkFn(scope);
        element.append(content);
    }
}
});
```

my url in  is displayed as

```
 http://localhost/'https://examples.form.io/simple'
```

How do I remove the prefix http://localhost

Seen the answers for the below questions but it didn't helped

[Why is my JS putting a prefix to my links (localhost:3000/mylink)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27530329/why-is-my-js-putting-a-prefix-to-my-links-localhost3000-mylink)

[Removing http:// prefix from ASP loaded URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404517/removing-http-prefix-from-asp-loaded-url)

Comment: Well, can you tell me what do you need instead of what you don't want ? It would be easier for me to help you.

Comment: Final template should be like this    <formio src="'https://examples.form.io/simple'"></formio>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something else has to be going on because I just took your code and put it in a fiddle and its working fine: [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/p030ms56/).  Something else has to be going on.

Comment: but that single quotes is required for my form.io src

Comment: You can see the url: http://localhost//'https://examples.form.io/simple'   .  What documentation are you referencing that makes you believe the sindle quotes are required?  You are double quoting it in your template.

Comment: I am not arguing, but in my output I have http://localhost/'https://examples.form.io/simple'  , there I have http://localhost is the extra thing

Comment: See above, I just took your code and tested it and it worked.  Did you modify your example before posting?

Comment: Now I removed the cache and checked, its working.. Thank you very much